# JQuery Dropdown change action in MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown with two option in it which I query from my model list, I want to use this dropdown option to displace Two view.

First-Choice display is a dropdown box if the data already exist.
Second-Choice Display a Form to add new record.

this is the view

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="control-group offset3">
                                <label for="text" class="control-label">Select Option</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentChoicesId, Model.ParentChoices, "-- Select Choice --", new { required = "true", id = "choice", @class = "input-xlarge" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div id="result">
                        <div class="row-fluid" id="newParent">
                        <div class="span6" >
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="text" class="control-label">Title</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.pTitleId, Model.pTitle, "-- Choose Title --", new { @class = "input-xlarge", required = "true" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="FirstName" class="control-label">First name</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pFirstName, new { @class = "input-xlarge", required = "true" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            .....

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="text" class="control-label">Nationality</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.pCountryId, Model.pCountry, "-- Choose Country --", new { required = "true", @class = "input-xlarge" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

...............

```
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row-fluid" id="existParent">
                        <div class="span6" >
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="text" class="control-label">Title</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ParentId, Model.Parents, "-- Choose Parent --", new { @class = "input-xlarge", required = "true" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

This is the controller am quering my options

```
var parentChoice = GetParentChoice().Select(t => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = t.Value,
            Text = t.Text
        });
        model.ParentChoices = parentChoice.AsEnumerable();


public static IQueryable<SelectListItem> GetParentChoice()
    {
        var choiceList = new List<SelectListItem>() 
        {
        new SelectListItem{ Text="New Parent", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="Existing Parent", Value = "2" }
        };

        return choiceList.AsQueryable();
    }
```

here is the jquery code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#result").fadeOut(0);
    });

    var selectedChoice;

    $("#choice").change(function () {

        selectedChoice = $("#choice").val().trim();

        if (selectedChoice === "-- Select Choice --") {
            $("#result").fadeOut();
        }
        else if (selectedChoice.val() === 1) {
            $("#result").hide("#existParent")
            $("#result").empty().append("#newParent").fadeIn();
        }
    });

</script>
```

this is what I have done so far and I need please I need some help to complete it tankz for your time.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how can i get the dropdown to show the form based on what the user choose?

Comment: I want a situation were by, when a user choose Existing parent from the drop down it will show just the dropdown populated with parent from the database. If New Parent, I should show the form to fill in new parent data. that is what am trying to archive here thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, So i came up with this and it worked just fine form me thank anyway

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#result").fadeOut(0);
    });

    $("#choice").change(function () {

        selectedChoice = $("#choice").val();

        if (selectedChoice == 1) {
            $("#existParent").hide()
            $("#result").fadeIn();
            $("#newParent").show();
        }
        else if (selectedChoice == 2) {
            $("#newParent").hide()
            $("#result").fadeIn();
            $("#existParent").show();
        }
        else if (selectedChoice == 0)
        {
            $("#result").fadeOut(0);
        }

    });

</script>
```